# Python selenium unable to find element neither by class name nor xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm newbie in Selenium. I start to learn Selenium via book. And I struggle with unclear behavior of Selenium. For educational purposes I use this site: 
http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/ - I'm trying to find search button by its class name, (which is: class='button search button') or by it xpath

```
search_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/header/div/div[4]/form/div[1]/button')
```

or

```
search_button = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('button')
```

but each time selenium unable to find it. Please help me to understand reason of such behavior. Thank you

I used Selenium IDE and it shows me XPATH: //button[@type='submit']

when I tried to find element by xpath,I have got the same error and it is strange. Please advise.

My code is:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class HomePageTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        #create new Firefox session
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

        #navvigate to application home page
        cls.driver.get('http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/')

    def test_search__text_field_max_length(self):
        #get the search text box
        search_field=self.driver.find_element_by_id("search")

        #check maxlenght attribute st to 128
        self.assertEqual("128",search_field.get_attribute("maxlength"))

    def test_search_button_enabled(self):
        # get Search button
        search_button = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('button')

        # check Search button is enabled
        self.assertTrue(search_button.is_enabled())



    @classmethod
    def tearDown(self):
        #close the browser window
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: Please include any error messages you get.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
search_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="button search-button"]')
```

Comment: Error was in tearDown method . I would like to make bigger answer but I'm banned. :'-(  If there is educational part of forum?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the selenium IDE plugin, install and start recording. Click on the button you want and view how its target is recorded in the IDE.  Programmatically, selenium will accept the same xpaths and other selectors as the IDE.  After it's been recorded in the IDE, there is a pull down on the target field that lets you see all the different ways you can select that element, ie xpath vs. by class etc.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

you might try:

```
css=button.button.search-button
//button[@type='submit']
//form[@id='search_mini_form']/div/button
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your locator isn't specific enough. There is more than one `button` on the page and more than one element with class=button on the page. This CSS selector is working for me.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[title='Search']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way using `xpath locator`

**Explanation:** Use `title` attribute of `<button>` tag.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Search']")
```

> OR

**Explanation:** Use `title` and `type` attribute of `<button>` tag.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Search'][@type='submit']")
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it's resolved your issue.